# how to show grouped items (GridView group) with a format of: one big picture and the rest are small (example attached)

Tags: gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml, itemspaneltemplate

I want that every of my group in the GridView will be in this specific structure/template (one big item and the rest in the same size):
[image]

The items should fill the screen till there is no more space in the buttom. It should be filled from right to left (when one column of items is filled then we fill the next column).
My view model exposes grouped collection, and I want the GridView to take every "little" item and locate it as if the big item is the "ceiling" of the GridView.

I think it has something to do with VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Here is my current code (currently every items is in the same size and the flow is from right to left):

```
            <GridView   
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        x:Name="GridMenu"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedArticlesViewSource}}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticlePreviewListView}">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}'
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamilyStyle}"
                                               Foreground="DarkBlue"
                                               FontSize="20"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>

                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the sample provided by microsoft. [See this thread on win8 develeper forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423)

Answer (score 0):

I found this good one:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-beauty-tip-using

hope it will help to people (I write that 'cause I have to enter at least 30 characters :))